# How to transfer database query result to javascript function using JSP

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

I meet up a problem, when I query result from database, and wish the result can pass up to the javascript function. Please look at my code for more information...
How come alert will be print "no", it should print my database result. for example 1

```
<script language="javascript">
function editRecord(no)
{
    var f=document.form1;
    alert ("no");
//f.action='edit_delete.jsp?id='+no;
    f.submit();
}


try 
        {       
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();//載入驅動程式類別
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp?user=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=big5");
         stmt=con.prepareStatement("select id, no, name from test");
         rs = stmt.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()) {
                  int test = rs.getInt("no");
            out.print("<tr><td>");
            out.print(rs.getString("id"));
            out.print("</td><td>");
            out.print(rs.getString("no"));
            out.print("</td><td>");
            out.print(rs.getString("name"));
            out.print("</td><td>");
            out.println("<input type='button' value='test10'   onclick='editRecord(\""+test+"\");'>"); 
            out.print(test);
                    out.print("</td></tr>");
        }
        %>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `alert(no)`?

Comment: Please ignore my question, how to close this question. I'm unable to post question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use scriptlets, use jstl. A definitely don't put your db connection in your jsp

You'll have to output java directly to an inline javascript within your jsp :

```
<script>
var myVar = "${myBean.myVal}";
</script>
```